# How often is cache cleared in React Native app?

Tags: react-native, caching, image-editor

I'm using RNCamera to take a picture. The path to the picture taken is in the file systems cache. Something like this:

"file:///data/user/0/com.find/cache/Camera/1986b5f9-4770-a255-543703fc6597.jpg"

Then I use the [react native image editor](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-editor) to crop this image and I get another file. Something like this:

"file:///data/user/0/com.find/cache/ReactNative_cropped_image_8510242.jpg"

These files are (according to the filepath of the images, at least) stored in the cache on the phone.

My question is this:
How long can I be sure that these images will remain in the cache? Do they get cleared when the app is closed? Or will they remain until I delete them myself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*This Thread is old but for those who need it:*

So, i've been working with RNCamera since 2 weeks now and i had the same question, but sadly i couldn't find any answer. I now checked with react-native-fs and it seems like the images are stored for the whole Camera session or maybe even the whole app session, thats the thing i could not find out.
But they still stay cached after reusing the RNCamera